# Claws Mail filter rule when `to` is the same as `from`

Tags: email-filter, claws-mail

Is it possible to have a rule for filter that will test if `to` email is the same as `from`?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible.

When setting a rule for filtering or processing that matches To and From, you can do this in their respective configuration window.

On the "Condition" line, click on "Define..."

Next, set Match criteria to Header. Then for Name, select From. Input what value you want the Header to contain. Click on Add.

Click on the condition you just created, then press Add. This will create a duplicate condition. Click on the duplicate condition and for Name, select To. Click Replace, then press OK.

Now you need to define your action for the condition you have just defined. Once done adding the action, add the rule. The rule will need a name first.